# How to change host platform type to linux/arm from linux/amd on Visual Studio 2019 configuration?

Tags: docker, arm, blazor

I want to deploy a Blazor app to QNAP(TS-230).
So, I build a Docker image by Visual Studio 2019.

QNAP is one of NAS, and is ARM system.
So, I have changed a dockerfile to following config.

```
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim-arm64v8 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorApp4/BlazorApp4.csproj", "BlazorApp4/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BlazorApp4/BlazorApp4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlazorApp4"
RUN dotnet build "BlazorApp4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Then build, I encountered following an error message.

```
error CTC1015: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
```

How to change target the host platform?

A reproduce step is here:

1. Execute VS2019
2. Select Blazor Server App
3. Select .NET 3.1
4. Check Enable Docker
5. Select Docker host to "Linux"
6. Select Public, Docker Container Repository.
7. Select "Docker hub"
8. Enter my username, and password
9. Change target runtime to "linux-arm"
10. build

Please teach me, How to change host platform type to linux/arm.

Best regard.

Comment: My environment is Windows 10.

Comment: You should probably add some tags around docker as your question has very little to do with Blazor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yes, my purpose is to deploy to Linux/arm. So, what it is Blazer or not is not important. Where do I add the tag on VS2019. I cannot find it..

Comment: Oh! I understand your saying! Thank you your advice, very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved by myself.
I used "buildx" that is provided by Docker.
This tool can build for specified platform by setting `--platform` parameter.
"buildx" is explained by following page.

https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/

And then, I did two change to Dockerfile.
First an using runtime/sdk image change to following.

1. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm64v8 AS base
2. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-buster-arm64v8 AS build

Second is that I added `-r linux-arm64` parameter to `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, and `dotnet publish`.

1. RUN dotnet restore "*.csproj" -r linux-arm64
2. RUN dotnet build "*.csproj" -r linux-arm64 -c Release -o /app/build
3. RUN dotnet publish "*.csproj" -r linux-arm64 -c Release -o /app/publish

Then at last, I executed following command,  I succeed !!!!!!!

`docker buildx build -f <Dockerfile path> --platform linux/arm64 -t <dockerhud path> --push .`

Attention, If you don't specify "-f" parameter, Relative paths writtern on Dockerfie is invalid.